# 234-Tree insertion method issues

Tags: java, algorithm, 2-3-4-tree

I am having an issue adding values that would create a new level in my 234 tree beyond the first level. My method creates children on the root object but fail to create children for any other node. I am able to create and insert a given number of data objects, as long as they don't fill a node causing it to create a child node...I have seriously been combing through this for days.

My question is basically based on my code. Are my methods (specifically the insertion methods) allowing for the creation of child nodes below the root?

**The Tree Class**

```
public class Tree234 {

    public Node root = new Node();  // make root node

    public int find(String key) {
        Node focus = root;
        int childNumber;
        while (true) {
            if ((childNumber = focus.findItem(key)) != -1) {
                return childNumber;               // found it
            } else if (focus.isLeaf()) {
                return -1;                        // can't find it
            } else // search deeper
            {
                focus = getNextChild(focus, key);
            }
        }  // end while
    }
    // insert a DataItem

    public void insert(String dWord) {  // Performs the splits
    // in a top-down (root -----> leaf) fashion.
        Node focus = root;

        DataItem tempItem = new DataItem(dWord);

        while (true) {

            if (focus.isFull()) { // if node full
                System.out.println("Need to split!");
                split(focus);   // split it
                System.out.println("Splint done?");                
                focus = focus.getParent();      // back up
                // search once
                focus = getNextChild(focus, dWord);
            } // end if (node is full)
            else if (focus.isLeaf()) {  // if node is leaf  
                break;                  // jump to insert
            } else {    // node is not full, not a leaf; so go to lower level 
                focus = getNextChild(focus, dWord);
            }

        }  // end while

        // insert new DataItem
        focus.insertItem(tempItem);

    }    // end insert

    public void split(Node thisNode) { // split the node

        // assumes node is full
        DataItem itemB, itemC;
        Node parent, child2, child3;
        int itemIndex;

        // two right most items are removed from the node and stored
        itemC = thisNode.removeItem();  // remove items from
        itemB = thisNode.removeItem();  // this node
        child2 = thisNode.disconnectChild(2);   // remove children
        child3 = thisNode.disconnectChild(3);   // from this node

        // make new node, goes to the right of the node being split
        Node newRight = new Node();

        if (thisNode == root) { // if this is the root
            // make new root
            root = new Node();
            // root is our parent
            parent = root;
            // connect to parent
            root.connectChild(0, thisNode);
        } else {// this node not the root get parent
            parent = thisNode.getParent();
        }
        // deal with parent

        // item B is inserted in the parent node
        itemIndex = parent.insertItem(itemB); // deal with parent
        // total items?
        int n = parent.getNumItems();

        // move parent's connections
        // one child to the right
        for (int j = n - 1; j < itemIndex; j--) {
            Node temp = parent.disconnectChild(j);
            parent.connectChild(j + 1, temp);
        }
        // connect newRight to parent
        parent.connectChild(itemIndex + 1, newRight);

        // deal with newRight
        newRight.insertItem(itemC);             // item C to newRight
        newRight.connectChild(0, child2);       // connect to 0 and 1
        newRight.connectChild(1, child3);       // on newRight
    }   // end split()

    public Node getNextChild(Node theNode, String keyWord) {

        int j;
        // assumes node is not empty, not full, not a leaf
        int numItems = theNode.getNumItems();

        // for each item in node
        for (j = 0; j < numItems; j++) {
            // is the value given less than the value at the 
            //first index of the array?                           
            if (keyWord.compareToIgnoreCase(theNode.getItem(j).dData) < 0) {
                // if so, return left child so we can use it at another 
                // point in time
                return theNode.getChild(j);
            }

        } // end for
        return theNode.getChild(j);
        // otherwise, our value is greater we're greater, so
        // we return right child (the child right after the 
        // value given, greater)        
    }

    public void displayTree() {
        recDisplayTree(root, 0, 0);
    }

    public void recDisplayTree(Node thisNode, int level, int childNumber) {
        System.out.print("level=" + level + " child=" + childNumber + " ");
        thisNode.displayNode();               // display this node

        // call ourselves for each child of this node
        int numItems = thisNode.getNumItems();
        for (int j = 0; j < numItems + 1; j++) {
            Node nextNode = thisNode.getChild(j);

            if (nextNode != null) {
                recDisplayTree(nextNode, level + 1, j);
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
    }         // end recDisplayTree()

}
```

Normally I would only post the specific code I am inquiring about. However this particular method jumps into the other two classes as well. So I thought seeing how I have them set up would be of some benefit.

**The Node Class**

```
public class Node {
    // Max size
    private static final int SIZE = 4;

    public int numItems;
    public Node parent;
    public Node children[] = new Node[SIZE];
    public DataItem items[] = new DataItem[SIZE - 1];

    public void connectChild(int childNum, Node child) {    //  Connect child to this Node
        children[childNum] = child;
        if (child != null) {
            child.parent = this;
        }
    }

    public Node disconnectChild(int childNum) { //  Disconnect child from this Node
        Node temp = children[childNum];
        children[childNum] = null;
        return temp;
    }

    public Node getChild(int childNum) {    // Returns child
        return children[childNum];
    }

    public Node getParent() {   // Returns parent
        return parent;
    }

    public Boolean isLeaf() {
        // test if child is a leaf
        return children[0] == null;
    }

    public int getNumItems() {
        return numItems;
    }

    public DataItem getItem(int index) {
        return items[index];
    }

    public Boolean isFull() {
        return numItems == SIZE - 1;
    }

    public int findItem(String term) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {

            if (items[j] == null) {
                break;
            } else if (items[j].dData.equalsIgnoreCase(term)) {
                return j;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }     // end findItem()

    public int insertItem(DataItem newItem) {
        if (findItem(newItem.dData) != -1) {
            items[findItem(newItem.dData)].count++;
            return 0;
        }
        numItems++; // will add new item
        String newKey = newItem.dData;

        for (int j = numItems-1; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (items[j] != null){
                System.out.println(items[j].dData);

            }
            if (items[j] == null) {
            continue;
            } else {
                String itsKey = items[j].dData;
                if (newKey.compareToIgnoreCase(itsKey) < 0) {
                    items[j + 1] = items[j];
                } else {
                    items[j + 1] = newItem;
                    return j + 1;
                }
            }   // end else (not null)
        }       // end for  ---->   //  shifted all items,
        items[0] = newItem;     //  insert new item
        return 0;

    }   // end insertItem()

    public DataItem removeItem() {
        DataItem temp = items[numItems - 1];
        items[numItems - 1] = null;
        numItems--;
        return temp;
    }

    public void displayNode() {
        for (int j = 0; j < numItems; j++) {
            items[j].displayItem();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}   // end class Node
```

I have everything set to public right now as I am just testing the structure of the code.

**The DataItem Class**

```
public class DataItem {

    public String dData;
    public int count;

    public DataItem(String term) {
        dData = term;
        count = 1;
    }
    public String getItem() {
        return this.dData;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return this.count;
    }
    public void displayItem() {
        System.out.print("\nWord: " + dData + "\t\tCount: " + count);
    }
}
```

Here is how I am adding DataItem objects to the tree.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Tree234 tree = new Tree234();

        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
            String temp = RandomName.getLast();
            System.out.println(temp);
            tree.insert(temp); 
        }
        tree.displayTree();                    
}
```

**Output**

```
    Townsend
    George
    Townsend
    Welch
    Townsend
    Clemons
    George
    Rose
    George
    Bond
    Townsend
    Clemons
    Bowers
    Clemons
    Bond
    Foreman
    Townsend
    George
    Clemons
    Hahn
    Townsend
    Alston
    Bond
    Petersen
    Townsend
    Hahn
    Hansen
    George
    Hahn
    Moses
    Hansen
    level=0 child=0 
    Word: George            Count: 1
    Word: Petersen          Count: 1
    level=1 child=0 
    Word: Bowers            Count: 1
    level=2 child=0 
    Word: Alston            Count: 1
    Word: Bond          Count: 1
    level=2 child=1 
    Word: Clemons           Count: 1
    Word: Foreman           Count: 1
    level=1 child=1 
    Word: Hahn          Count: 1
    Word: Hansen            Count: 1
    Word: Moses         Count: 1
    level=1 child=2 
    Word: Townsend          Count: 1
```

The tree "seems" to work, however adding more than 10 names starts to make it unstable. It is unable to process 15 or more at all.

Output with 15 or more

```
    Bowman
    Moore
    Bowman
    Anthony
    Moore
    Bowman
    Graham
    Moore
    Nielsen
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    Moore
    Camacho
    Bowman
    Graham
    Herman
    Graham
    Gallagher
    Moore
    Bowman
    Camacho
    Hartman
    Herman
    Daniels
    Gallagher
    Camacho
    Snyder
        at dataPackage.Tree234.insert(Tree234.java:40)
        at testPackage.Main.main(Main.java:31)
    X:\source\234Tree\234Tree\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1040: The following error occurred while executing this line:
    X:\source\234Tree\234Tree\nbproject\build-impl.xml:805: Java returned: 1
    BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I am still fairly new to algorithms so I could totally be missing something simple. I am starting to think the insertion methods are fine, but I may not be splitting correctly. Which is why I can insert to level 2 now and not farther. Thanks for any insight you may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected!! I was splitting the nodes incorrectly in the tree class.

```
for (int j = n - 1; j < itemIndex; j--) { // in this line  I had a '<' and should have
    Node temp = parent.disconnectChild(j); // had a '>' 
    parent.connectChild(j + 1, temp);
}
```

Thanks for to anyone one who was looking at this with me.